# Error getting the value and key of a Combo Box in C#

Tags: c#

I honestly can't find and don't see a solution to this error. I go to you to help me solve it.

What it does is when one select select get the url extension and then call it. how is this possible?

My code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> ldict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
ldict.Add("USA", ".com");
ldict.Add("MEX", ".com.mx");
ldict.Add("ESP", ".es");
ldict.Add("CAN", ".ca");
ldict.Add("FRA", ".fr");
ldict.Add("UKA", ".co.uk");
ldict.Add("ITA", ".it");
CountryCombo.DataSource = ldict.ToList();
CountryCombo.ValueMember = "Value";
CountryCombo.DisplayMember = "Key";
CountryCombo.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

How do I get the value and the key to make a call like this:

```
string key = ((KeyValuePair)CountryCombo.SelectedItem).Key;
string value = ((KeyValuePair)CountryCombo.SelectedItem).Value;
```

Comment: You should use `KeyValuePair<string, string>`, I guess

Answer (score 0):

Use a list based on the key collection as your datasource

```
CountryCombo.DataSource = new List<string>(ldict.Keys);
```

Then use selected item as the key for the dictionary to get your 'value':

```
var value = ldict[(string)CountryCombo.SelectedItem];
```